# evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk \sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)\right)$

Tags: integration

I'd like to get some direction or hint for how to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk \sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)\right)$$

It looks like I can rewrite it as a proper integral but not sure how.

Comment: Hint:Convert it into Riemann sum of integral of some function.It's value is $\int_{0}^{1}x\sin(\frac{π}{2}x)dx$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
$$\begin{gather*}  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b-a}n \sum_{k=1}^n
 f \left( a +k\frac{b-a}n \right) =\int_a^bf(x) \ dx \end{gather*}$$
Notice you can write your expression as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\pi k}{2n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}x\sin x\,dx.$$

If you prefer, you could instead take $a=0,b=1$ and write as $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\,dx$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: does it come up to be $\frac{2}{\pi}$ ?

Comment: @aradarbel10 sorry, there was a typo: the answer is $\dfrac{4}{\pi^2}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may recall that Riemann sum gives us the following formula for a function $f\in C^1$:

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1n\sum_{k=0}^n f\left(\frac kn\right)=\int_0^1f(x) dx.$$

Here you are led to evaluate
$$
I:=\int_0^1x \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}2 \right)\, dx
$$
Hope you can take it from here.